# Power Query - Dynamically Merge and Sum Columns

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

After some transformations, i get a following table, where each column = week number with some value.
Due to week split between months, I get some columns which I need to sum.

In example bellow - Column "48" and "481" should be summed and named "48".

[image]

Is it possible to dynamically sum columns based on first two numbers ? (XX = sum of XX & XX1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an index.
[image]

Select index column and unpivot other columns
[image]

Select attribute column and extract first two chars.
[image]

[image]

Group and sum.

[image]

Pivot back.

[image]

[image]